# Which Algorithm is faster?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, code-complexity

Our Lecturer gave us his code

```
procedure linear_search (x: integer; a1, a2, …, an: integers)
   i := 1
   while ( i ≤ n and x ≠ ai )
     i := i + 1
     if i ≤ n then
        location := i
     else
        location := 0
```

and this is mine

```
method Search (x integer, a1,a2....an integers)
   for i from 1 to n
   start
       if ai = x, location = i, break.
       else i++, location = 0.
   stop
```

In terms of steps, my code takes `2n + 1` steps to finish while the other code takes `2n + 2`, therefore my code is logically faster. However, in Big O terms, they're both `O(n)`. 
So what do I say, which one is faster? Or do I say they're equal?

Comment: That's not how big-O and algorithm analysis works. You either find an asymptotical bound that shows one is better than the other, or you do an empirical test

Comment: If you have two horses, there's a good way to find out which runs faster (and it's not by going to whichhorseisfaster.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @nhgrif I already tried using a compiler to test but the timings were different upon each run.

Comment: @thethiny That's why you use a proper benchmark and try to get a [statistical significance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as big-O is concerned, the two are equal: you can freely subtract constants and divide by constants, so both algorithms are linear in the number of their inputs - i.e. they are O(n).

In general, big-O will not tell you exactly how fast an algorithm is. It boils everything down to a formula that describes how fast would performance or memory consumption degrade if you were to increase the size of the input, giving you a measure suitable for comparisons.

This by no means provides a complete picture, only a rough estimate. Other important things, such as cache and branching efficiency, can make one program much faster than the other program, even when they both implement algorithms with the same big-O efficiency measure.